# IdeaVim create custom command

Tags: intellij-idea, command, ideavim

Is there any way of creating custom commands with IdeaVim (like `:command` in `vim`)? Trying to run `:command ... ...` spits out `Not an editor command: command`.

Comment: What exactly are you going to use it for? IdeaVim supports mapping commands using `:map` and friends. It also supports its custom `:action` command for running IDE actions. See [the docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim).

Comment: So there is no way? I'd also like to be able to define something like `:cn<CR>` instead of having to `:action GotoNextError<CR>`.

Comment: you can do that
`nnoremap <space>e :action GotoNextError<cr>`

Answer (score 1):

You can register custom commands with IdeaVim by adding something like the following to *~/.ideavimrc*.

```
command! Reformat action ReformatCode
```

And invoke it with `:Reformat`.